# index used after Split function (jquery)?

Tags: split, jquery

I am having a click handler  for three buttons and inside this handler I want to extract ID of the button clicked. I have a line of code  like this:

```
$('#switch button').click(function(){
    var class=this.id.split('-')[1];
    // rest of the code 
});
```

I do  understand the split method, but can't understand  `[1] index` in  the end?

Assume that  I  have a id  named say `switch-default`.

Comment: Your code does not extract class name, but rather the **id** of the clicked element. To get class name, change the code to this: `var class = this.className;`

Comment: @ShadowWizard  correct. I have edited my question.

Comment: Cheers, as the answers all say the code will give the second part after splitting by `-` for example for such button: `<button id="my-first-button">first</button>` it will be "first".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the index of the element in the newly created array, so `[1]` refers to the second element. To make it clear:

```
var classes = this.id.split('-');
console.log(classes[0] + " " + classes[1]); // outputs "switch default"
```

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split

Answer (score 4):

`string.split()` returns an array. Example:

```
var foo = "example-123";
var bar = foo.split("-");     // => ["example", "123"]
var baz = foo.split("-")[1];  // => "123", the same as bar[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The split function returns an array.  As such you can select elements of the array using the [1].  Arrays element indexes start at 0, so the first element is 0 and the second is 1 and so on.